# Macbook Pro, Restart in Sleep Mode/Idle-Mode

Tags: sleep-wake, crash

i have a Problem with my Mid 2012 Macbook Pro (MacbookPro9,2).
Sometimes when i close the lid, it is restarting after some time. This is also hearable by the start sound. No special Software is running at this time. I am not using VMWare Fusion and also Parallels is shut down at this moment.
Here is the Crash report:

[Crash Report Pastebin][1]https://pastebin.com/5346zkn4

Currently i am running High Sierra.
Thanks or your help.

Comment: can you check if "install macOS updates" is selected in System Preferences -> App Store -> Automatically Check For Updates

Comment: Yes this is active

Comment: I deactivated it and the system seems to restart less, but still does.